# Why my useEffect did not work 'GET' data until i have to rewrite the props to other components...?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try to 'GET' the 'user info' from the server.

API GET url is : /users/${memberId}
userID is number type memberId (Ex. 4)

Below are my Questions..

I should Link the Page and Load the correct userInfo when I click the "userIcon"on the "  "

When i try to check the page directly to localhost , it doesn't show up.
But When i delete the " userId={userData.memberId} " then the page has showed up and rewrite the
" userId={userData.memberId} " and save , then also the page was okay.

```
//Header.tsx

useEffect(() => {
    const userGetData = async () => {
      return call(`/users`, 'GET', null)
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res[0]
        setUserData(data);
      });
    };

    userGetData();
  }, [])

...

return(
...
  <div>
      <LoginHeader changeNav={isUser.isLogin} userID={userData.memberId} />
   </div>
)
```

" userId={userData.memberId} " in the  is for the Link to path the UserPage.
this is console.log(userData)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AryO1.png)

```
//LoginHeader.tsx
// UserIcon
            <Link to={`/users/${userID}`}
            state={{userID: userID}}
            className="relative p-2 text-gray-500 bg-transparent"
            >
              <img/>
            </Link>
```

The problem is when i click that UserIcon, It does not work and the error.
The error told me <<Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'memberId')>>

So.. Why my code did not work? : click usericon -> go to UserPage with uerl /users/${memberId}.
And Why the useEffect 'GET' does not work before i delete the memberId props in LoginHeader ???

Answer (score 0):

> Why my code did not work?

Because `userData` is `undefined`.  You don't show where/how you initialize it, but presumably it's something like this?:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
```

That would initialize it to `undefined`.  So when the component first renders you can't read properties from `userData`, because it's `undefined`.  It might have a value *at some later time*, but the code will already have thrown an error by then.

One option would be to initialize it to an empty object:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
```

In which case `userData.memberId` won't throw an error, but will pass an `undefined` value to that component.

Another option is to not render the component until `userData` has a value:

```
<div>
  { userData ? <LoginHeader changeNav={isUser.isLogin} userID={userData.memberId} /> : null }
</div>
```

What option you prefer is really up to you.  But the main thing is that you can't read a property from `undefined`.